# CFBundleDocumentTypes Not Registering

Tags: ios, ios6, zip, info.plist, uti

Right now I am making a document based app for iOS. I am currently trying to register .zip for opening with my app. I have tried apple's example and many other tutorials such as the one [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app/). However, none of them make my app show up in mail.app or any other app. I have even tried removing the app and then running it with no luck. If it makes a difference, I am running iOS 6. A part of info.plist is below:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Zip File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I handle zip files and have this:

```
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>ZIP</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
            <string>public.zip-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Comment: With this, your app doesn't appear when you select the "Open In..." option for an email attachment?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Thats what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Isn't this interesting, It doesn't work on an iPad but it COMPLETELY works on an iPhone. Very Weird.

Answer (score -2):

It Turns out it works on an iPhone but not on an iPad. It must be a bug in iOS 6 or the fact that this was an iPhone only project and not an Universal app.